# How to use sed with user input

Tags: unix, scripting

Script performs two things

1.Enables the user input a file name

2.Enables the user to input a line number to view the content

```
echo "Enter the file name"
read fname
  find / -name "$fname" > /tmp/newone.txt

if test $? -eq 0
then
 {
  echo "File found"
  echo "The no of line in the file $fname is `cat /tmp/newone.txt | wc|awk '{pri
nt $1}'`"
  echo  "Enter the line no"
  read  lcnt
  sed '"$lcnt" p' "$fname"
 }
else
 {
   echo "File not found"
 }
fi
```

Issue 
1.Getting error in the sed part

Error message "sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command"

how to rectify it ?

2.Can i redirect the output of 'find' to a variable

For example

$flloc =/tmp/newone.txt

so i will be able to use '$flloc' instead of the absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This is how you'd go about using your variable in the sed command:

```
echo "Line no: "
read lcnt

sed -n "$lcnt p" $fname
```

What was wrong with your original expression is that bash variables aren't interpreted when you use single quotes. Example:

```
lcnt=5

# prints $lcnt
echo '$lcnt'

# prints 5
echo "$lcnt"
```

2) To store your find output to a variable, simply do this:

```
floc=`find / -name $fname` # Here I'm using backticks, not single quotes.
```

Comment: when i tried 'floc=`find / -name $fname`' getting error message 'Permission denied'

Comment: i got it  issue was due to some space in the assignment

Comment: I should've mentioned this, but you're going to run into problems if your find command finds more than one file of the same name. What you really need to do is reconsider having the user input the whole path and verify if the file exists after. Using find will also cause your script to run an unnecessarily long time especially if the user already knows which file he/she wants to use.